# How to Make a Nullable Field in Proto3 for a HTTP Response?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, proto3

I want to return an object as an HTTP response where one of its fields is nullable. The problem is proto3 won't let me do it easily. This happens because I parsed a pointer of string to a string, so when the pointer points to null it produces this error
`runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`

I have attempted to solve this by at least these two work-arounds I learned from the Internet.

### 1. Using oneof

exercise.proto (the message definition)

```
message ExercisesData {
    string Serial = 1 [json_name="serial"];
    string Title = 2 [json_name="title"];
    oneof OptionalSubmissionSerial {
       string SubmissionSerial = 3 [json_name="submission_serial"];
}
```

mapper.go (to parse a Go struct to fit the proto message)

```
exercise := &Exercise.ExercisesData {
           Serial:                   e.Serial,
           Title:                    e.Title,
           OptionalSubmissionSerial: &Exercise.ExercisesData_SubmissionSerial{
                SubmissionSerial: *e.SubmissionInfo.LatestSubmissionSerial,
           },
}
```

### 2. Using google/protobuf/wrappers.proto

exercise.proto (the message definition)

```
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

message ExercisesData {
    string Serial = 1 [json_name="serial"];
    string Title = 2 [json_name="title"];
    google.protobuf.StringValue SubmissionSerial = 3 [json_name="submission_serial"];
}
```

mapper.go (to parse a Go struct to fit the proto message)

```
exercise := &Exercise.ExercisesData {
           Serial:                   e.Serial,
           Title:                    e.Title,
           SubmissionSerial:         &wrappers.StringValue{
                Value: *e.SubmissionInfo.LatestSubmissionSerial,
            },
}
```

### Expected Result

Both ways still produce the same error message, the only difference is the line of code it refers to. That's why I am so helpless. The expected HTTP response would look like this

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "serial": "EXC-NT2OBHQT",
            "title": "Title of Topic Exercise",
            "submission_serial": null
        }
     ]
}
```

I really hope anyone can help me to find a way to define **a nullable field in proto3 for a Http response and how to parse it from a struct**. Thank you!

Comment: Which line of code that causes the nil pointer error?

Comment: the one where I set the value of SubmissionSerial in mapper.go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out I find another workaround that actually works! It's using google/protobuf/wrappers.proto but I gotta tweak it a lil' bit in the mapper. Here's how it goes:

#### exercise.proto (the message definition)

```
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

message ExercisesData {
    string Serial = 1 [json_name="serial"];
    string Title = 2 [json_name="title"];
    google.protobuf.StringValue SubmissionSerial = 3 [json_name="submission_serial"];
}
```

### mapper.go (to parse a Go struct to fit the proto message)

```
import "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/wrappers"

        exercise := &pbExercise.GetExercisesData{
            Serial:              e.Serial,
            Title:               e.Title,
        }

        if e.SubmissionInfo.LatestSubmissionSerial != nil {
            exercise.SubmissionSerial = &wrappers.StringValue{
                Value: *e.LatestSubmissionSerial,
            }
        }
```

Comment: Gave me an idea for my use-case

Answer (score 1):

I assume you set `syntax = proto3;`. I don't think there is a way to achieve what you are after at this moment. Go check [this issue](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf/issues/218).

But if you are willing to live with

```
{"serial":"serial","title":"title"}
```

where `submission_serial` is altogether missing as opposed to

```
{"serial":"serial","title":"title","submission_serial":null}
```

than the following works just fine

```
// ...
data := &ExercisesData{Serial: "serial", Title: "title"}

out, err := proto.Marshal(data)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatalln("failed to encode: ", err)
}

buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
marshaler := jsonpb.Marshaler{}

err = marshaler.Marshal(buf, data)

data2 := &ExercisesData{}
if err := proto.Unmarshal(out, data2); err != nil {
  log.Fatalln("failed to parse: ", err)
}
// ...
```